# When reverse item loaded on one factor when they are not supposed to

Tags: spss, experiment-design

I'm conducting a survey online and one of my measurement is 'Credibility' variable, which uses total of 9 variable (see image). These variables are supposed to fall into three dimensions, which are credibility, expertise, and attractiveness. However, the three questions which are not related to each other loaded on one factor (2) and rest on the other side.

Can this mean that people were not paying attention?

While my initial expectation is that all of these 9 variable (or at least most) to be significant (in anova), however, those three that were reverse coded were only ones that are significant. What could this mean?

Could someone help me to find problem in this, so I can conduct successful manipulation?

Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: No, it is not likely the result of people not paying attention -- that would likely result in very low correlations and low factor loadings.  It is more likely that something is wrong either with your theory or your questions.

For your second question: Being reverse coded shouldn't have anything to do with the results of an ANOVA. That part is likely a coincidence. But have you checked the assumptions of the model? Colinearity seems likely, given the names of your variables.